# Gradle: Include project without knowing the details of its subprojects

Tags: gradle

Let's say we have the below project structure.

```
A depends on B
B depends on C
```

I want project A, such that it does not know anything about project C. It should only know about its direct dependency project B. Project B should contain all the information about how it depends on project C.

The specifics of all projects must be in their own gradle files.

To be more concrete let's say there should be the following task dependence

```
task build in A must depend on task build from B
task build in B must depend on task build from C
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
project(':a') {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    evaluationDependsOn(':b') // possibly not required but worth a mention
    dependencies {
        // add the 'foo' configuration to the 'compile' dependencies
        compile project(path: ':b', configuration: 'foo')
    }
}

project(':b') {
    configurations {
         foo
    }
    task makeCustomJar(type: Jar) {
         // configure the jar task
    }
    artifacts {
         // the custom jar is added to the 'foo' configuration
         foo makeCustomJar
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not been explicit, that projects should be in their own gradle files. I have updated the question.

Comment: Could I use "apply from" for this?

Comment: It doesn't matter. If separate gradle file per project then just extract the body of the `project(...) { ... }` blocks. Could I use "apply from" for this - NO